# how to get values of the _variant_t?

Tags: c++, excel, variant

I want to know how to get values of the _variant_t type.

I already know the method a value using GetItems(), e.g.:

```
_variant_t var = pRs->Fields->GetItem(i)->GetValue();
```

In the Excel file (.xls), I can't find the method that whole data of row.

Comment: I've got no idea what's being asked here. `variant_t` is clear, but where is `GetItems()` coming from? What does Excel have to do with this?

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to parse. "the method a value"? "the method that whole data of row"? `GetItems()` vs `GetItem()`?

Comment: Assuming none of the above long chain of prop-fetches and method executes throws an exception, was there a specific "value" you had in mind?, because you just fetched it (its *in* the returned `variant_t`, and maybe reading about those may help you solve your problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a collection of extractors you can use to extract data from the variant type. Just cast it to the type that variant represents. to get the inner type, check the 'vt' member.

Here is an article at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ew0bcz27%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A sample code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <cassert>

#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")

int main()
{
    _variant_t v(10.0);
    assert(v.vt == VT_R8); // inner type is double

    double value = static_cast<double>(v); // 10.0

    return 0;
}
```